# knockout cant process click binding as not a function

Tags: knockout.js

I am struggling calling a function with knockout!

```
var bankViewModel = function () {
    self.addBank = function(){
                return function(){
                    self.addShow(true);
                    var bank = new observableBank('',"","","","","","","","","Active");
                    self.newBank(bank);
                };
        };
};

var bankViewModelInstance = new bankViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(bankViewModelInstance, document.getElementById("company-info-bank"));
```

and in the view I have tried loads of variations of binding with:-

```
<button id="demo-btn-addrow" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa fa-plus" data-bind="click: addBank()">Add New</button>
```

tried $parent (undefined), $data - does nothing etc.

Can someone tell me what silly mistake I am making?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Graham consider closing down the question by marking it as answer . cheers

Answer (score 2):

Tough your code works well check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26814/)** .

*couple of corrections/Improvements :*

- you can use `data-bind="click: addBank"` no need to bind with `addBank()` inside click function which make `click` fire **onLoad** .
- Click function logic in viewModel you don't need to return a `function()`

**viewModel:**

```
var bankViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.newBank = ko.observableArray();
    self.addShow = ko.observable();
    self.addBank = function () {
        self.addShow(true);
        /*                    var bank = new observableBank('',"","","","","","","","","Active"); */
        self.newBank.push(1); //for testing

    };
};

var bankViewModelInstance = new bankViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(bankViewModelInstance);
```

sample working fiddler **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26813/)**